# Enabling zoom on scroll view

Tags: android, zooming, scrollview

I have certain data in placed in my `ScrollView`. I want to enable it to zoom in/ zoom out. It contains simple `ImageView` and `TextView`.

Any suggestions will be helpful.
Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/viewSoupMenu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/soupback" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/flowericon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnVegClearSoup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/btnvegsoupclearclickedxml" />

     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FrameLayout` and have a look at this official document: [Zooming a View](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html).

Comment: I guess that would just enable me to zoom the image. Im concerned about the text more

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class mentioned below for enabling Pinch Zoom in your `ImageView` and you can create a duplicate class of this class which extends `TextView` instead of `ImageView` for enabling zooming in it.

```
public class PinchZoomImageView extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener{

    public PinchZoomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        _init();
    }

    public PinchZoomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        _init();
    }

    public PinchZoomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        _init();
    }

    private void _init(){
        //setOnTouchListener(this);

        view = (ImageView) this;
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);

        metric = new DisplayMetrics();
        // Work around a Cupcake bug

        d_dpi=((0.52f/(metric.densityDpi))*240.0f)-0.52f;
        Log.d("ash","dpi= "+d_dpi);
        if(metric.densityDpi==160)
        d_dpi=0.34f;
        matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
        matrix.setScale((0.52f/800.0f)*metric.widthPixels+d_dpi, (0.52f/480.0f)*metric.heightPixels+d_dpi);
        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        bMap =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mfigure);
        btsize = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.map);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(hasFocus){
            init();
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        maxZoom = (3.0f/480.0f)*metric.heightPixels+d_dpi;
        minZoom = (0.52f/800.0f)*metric.widthPixels+d_dpi;
        height = view.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
        width = view.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

        // Handle touch events here...
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX()/metric.widthPixels * 800, event.getY()/metric.heightPixels * 480);
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
                mode = DRAG;
                click = true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                }
                click = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                if(click)
                    onClick(event.getX(), event.getY(),true);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {

                    temp_x = ((start.x) - ((event.getX()/metric.widthPixels)*800));
                    temp_y = ((start.y) - ((event.getY()/metric.heightPixels) * 480));               
                    if(FloatMath.sqrt(temp_x * temp_x + temp_y * temp_y)< 10)
                      break;

                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);

                    // limit pan
                    matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
                    float currentY = matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                    float currentX = matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                    float currentScale = matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                    float currentHeight = height * currentScale;
                    float currentWidth = width * currentScale;
                    float dx = (event.getX()/metric.widthPixels * 800) - start.x;
                    float dy = (event.getY()/metric.heightPixels * 480) - start.y;
                    float newX = currentX+dx;
                    float newY = currentY+dy;

                    RectF drawingRect = new RectF(newX, newY, newX+currentWidth, newY+currentHeight);
                    float diffUp = Math.min(viewRect.bottom-drawingRect.bottom, viewRect.top-drawingRect.top);
                    float diffDown = Math.max(viewRect.bottom-drawingRect.bottom, viewRect.top-drawingRect.top);
                    float diffLeft = Math.min(viewRect.left-drawingRect.left, viewRect.right-drawingRect.right);
                    float diffRight = Math.max(viewRect.left-drawingRect.left, viewRect.right-drawingRect.right);
                    if(diffUp > 0 ){
                        dy +=diffUp;
                    }
                    if(diffDown < 0){
                        dy +=diffDown;
                    }
                    if( diffLeft> 0){
                        dx += diffLeft;
                    }
                    if(diffRight < 0){
                        dx += diffRight;
                    }
                    matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
                    //selection.set(selection.x + dx, selection.y + dy);
                    click = false;
                }
                else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = newDist / oldDist;

                        matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
                        float currentScale = matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_X];

                        // limit zoom
                        if (scale * currentScale > maxZoom) {
                            scale = maxZoom / currentScale;
                        } else if (scale * currentScale < minZoom) {
                            scale = minZoom / currentScale;
                        }
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        float mv[] = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(mv);

        Log.d("PV", "Click x " + mv[Matrix.MTRANS_X] + " y " + mv[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] + " cx " + event.getX() + " cy " + event.getY());

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        view.invalidate();
        return true; // indicate event was handled
    }

     public void onClick(float x, float y,boolean state){
        Log.d("TAG","x="+x+" y "+y);
        float mv[] = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(mv);

        if(btsize != null)
            btsize.recycle();

        btsize = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.map);

        if(btSel != null)
            btSel.recycle();

        btSel = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mfigure);

        Canvas canvas;
        try{
            canvas = new Canvas(btsize);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            btsize = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.map).copy(Config.ARGB_8888,true);
            canvas = new Canvas(btsize);
        }

        x -= mv[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        y -= mv[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        float wdt = btsize.getWidth() * mv[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
        float ht = btsize.getHeight() * mv[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

        float tw = x/wdt;
        float th = y/ht;

        selPoint.set(tw, th);
        if(state)
             canvas.drawBitmap(btSel, (tw * btsize.getWidth()) - (btSel.getWidth()/2), (th * btsize.getHeight()) - (btSel.getHeight()/2), null);
        else
            canvas.drawBitmap(btSel, (x * btsize.getWidth()) - (btSel.getWidth()/2), (y * btsize.getHeight()) - (btSel.getHeight()/2), null);

        setImageBitmap(btsize);

    }

    /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
         float x = ((event.getX(0)/metric.widthPixels)*800) - ((event.getX(1)/metric.widthPixels)*800);
           float y = ((event.getY(0)/metric.heightPixels) * 480) - ((event.getY(1)/metric.heightPixels) * 480);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
         float x = ((event.getX(0)/metric.widthPixels) * 800) + ((event.getX(1)/metric.widthPixels)*800);
           float y = ((event.getY(0)/metric.heightPixels) * 480) + ((event.getY(1)/metric.heightPixels) * 480);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    private static final String TAG = "Touch";
    // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    // Limit zoomable/pannable image
    private ImageView view;
    private float[] matrixValues = new float[9];
    private float maxZoom;
    private float minZoom;
    private float height;
    private float width;
    private RectF viewRect;
    private float temp_x,temp_y;
    private boolean click = false;
    public PointF selPoint = new PointF();
    Bitmap bMap;
    private float d_dpi;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    private DisplayMetrics metric; 
    Bitmap bt = null;
    Bitmap btsize = null;
    Bitmap btSel = null;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering how I could do this with a textview as for the image view it uses 2 images(1 bitmap , and other original one) if I am not mistaken. Also, I actually wanted to do the zooming on button clicks. Any idea>

Comment: I am wondering, where do `0.52f`, `240.0f`, `160 dpi`, `800f` and `480f` come from?

Comment: @LasseMadsen This solution mentioned here was originally for a specific device (Samsung Galaxy S) resolution and for landscape orientation only. That's why there are hard coded values but with few efforts you can make it dynamic to support different resolutions. 0.52f is used as a minimum value proportion of the pixels and 3.0f as maximum means 3 times of pixels. 800 x 480 was device resolution in Landscape orientation. 160 is Ldpi  & 240 is hdpi.