# Scrollview zoom not scrolling left and right

Tags: android, scrollview, pinchzoom

I'm trying to make the ScrollView zoom-able following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19628186/4196092)

```
 mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context,
     new ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
     float scale = 1 - detector.getScaleFactor();

     float prevScale = mScale;
     mScale += scale;

     if (mScale < 0.1f) // Minimum scale condition:
     mScale = 0.1f;

     if (mScale > 10f) // Maximum scale condition:
     mScale = 10f;
     ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(
     1f / prevScale, 1f / mScale, 1f / prevScale,
     1f / mScale, detector.getFocusX(),
     detector.getFocusY());
     scaleAnimation.setDuration(0);
     scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

     startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
     return true;
     }


     });
```

but the zooming scrolls only work up and down, i'm trying to make it scroll left and right too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrollview only do Vertical scrolling while HorizontalScrollView does Horizontal scrolling.

No class (AFAIK) enable scrolling both axis, you can find on internet classes for that or write your own.